# Visual FoxPro OLEDB error: Invalid path or file name

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, asmx, visual-foxpro

We have Novell server and there Advantage Database Server 9.1 is installed and all other Xbase++ programs access DBF files from that location.
I want to access DBF files from C# asmx webservice.

Problem is if I use Visual FoxPro VFP OLEDB then it only works while running asmx webservice in Visual studio's Debug mode but when I publish it to IIS, it gives this error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Invalid path or file name
```

**First Attempt (with ADS OLEDB):**

It works ONLY when DBF files are not opened by non-ADS program. If any Xbase++ program first opens DBF file then "Locking situation" occurs and I can't access DBF file.

ADS connection string:

```
string connectionString = string.Format(@"Provider=Advantage OLE DB Provider;data source={0}; Advantage Server Type=ADS_REMOTE_SERVER;SecurityMode=ADS_IGNORERIGHTS;TableType=ADS_CDX;Locking=ADS_COMPATIBLE_LOCKING;", folderPath);
```

**Second Attempt (with VFP OLEDB):**

Then I tried VFP OLEDB but it only works when I run asmx webservice from Visual Studio's Debug mode and does not work after deployment to IIS, when I publish webservice to IIS it gives this error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Invalid path or file name.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
```

VFP connection string:

```
string connectionString = string.Format(@"Provider=vfpoledb.1;data source={0}; TableType=vfp;", folderPath);
```

Comment: As for the "Invalid path or file name" exception, Vfp DBC/DBF databases are File Servers, the current process trying to access them via VfpOleDB needs appropriate file-system privileges. IOW, if your code works in the Debugger but not at runtime, your current Windows user account apparently does have appropriate NTFS privileges and the IIS process at runtime might have not.