# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro: Invalid path or file name

Tags: iis, asp-classic, oledb, visual-foxpro

I'm able to connect to my VFP database when running my classic ASP site locally w/ Visual Studio and IIS Express but when I deploy to a server on IIS it get:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro: Invalid path or file name

From [a comment on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952445/visual-foxpro-oledb-error-invalid-path-or-file-name), I see the problem is probably related to **permissions** but I've got the application pool running under a domain account that has access to the UNC where the DB resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my authentication on anonymous access from `IUSR` to the `Application pool identity` and it started working.

`IIS Manager -> Website -> Authentication -> Anonymous Authentication -> Edit`

[image: iis auth anonymous setting]

After changing that, the database access must be using the service account now.  I guess there's a difference between ASP.NET and Classic ASP?

---

**References how I arrived at this answer**

I found [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6241e703-7f2e-456c-b64c-076ec52810db/oledb-provider-and-unc-path?forum=visualfoxprogeneral) which talked about anonymous access which got me thinking more about "classic asp run under service account".  That Google search [lead to me to this SO post](https://serverfault.com/a/37889/429274):

> Classic ASP runs impersonating the user who is authenticated to the server in the HTTP session.